# Faster Or Best Alternative for VBA to delete rows not containing specific values?

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question to save everybody's time:

I have the code below that works fine but is too slow for my 30,000+ lines.

It basically deletes all the rows not containing the states TX, AR, LA and OK from column AD.

```
Sub DeleteStateExceptions()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = iLastRow To 2 Step -1
        Select Case Cells(i, "AD").Value
            Case "TX"
            Case "OK"
            Case "AR"
            Case "LA"
            Case Else
                Rows(i).Delete
            End Select
    Next i
    'deletes row when cell in column AD is not TX, OK, AR or LA
End Sub
```

Any amendment to make it faster? Would you use a different logic?

Comment: Use `Union` to build up a range to delete, then delete once, after looping.

Comment: In your code use something like `Rows(i).Clear` instead and then do a sort at the very end to move blank rows to the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. It should be very fast:

```
Sub DeleteStateExceptions()
    Dim iLastRow As Long, arrMark, lastEmptyCol As Long, i As Long, boolDel As Boolean
    iLastRow = cells(rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    lastEmptyCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count + 1
    ReDim arrMark(1 To iLastRow - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        Select Case cells(i, "AD").value
            Case "TX", "OK", "AR", "LA"
            Case Else
                boolDel = True  'to delete only if at least a row has been marked
                arrMark(i - 1, 1) = "Del"
            End Select
    Next i
    If boolDel Then
        With cells(2, lastEmptyCol).Resize(UBound(arrMark), 1)
            .value = arrMark
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

An alternative would be to create a `Union` range, but in case of large ranges, creating of this one slows down the speed seriously. You can set a maximum cells limit (iterate backwards), let us say, 100, delete the rows already in the `Union` range and set it as `Nothing`.

But the above solution should be the fastest, in my opinion...

**Edited**:

I promised to come back and supply a solution overpassing the limitation of a specific number of arrays in a discontinuous range. I knew only about the 8192 for versions up to 2007 inclusive. It looks, such a limitation also exists in the newer versions, even if bigger. In order to test the above (much improved) way against the `Union` range version, I imagined the next testing way:

1. Place a constant declaration on top of the module keeping the testing code (in the declarations area):

```
 Private Const arrRepeat As Long = 5000
```

2. Copy the next code of a `Sub` building a similar environment to test the versions in a similar way, plus the sorting one:

```
3. Copy the improved above version, being extremely fast:
Sub DeleteStateExceptions()
    Dim iLastRow As Long, arrMark, lastEmptyCol As Long, i As Long, boolDel As Boolean
    Dim tm, arrSort
    
    buildTestingRange arrRepeat
    
    tm = Timer
    iLastRow = cells(rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    arrSort = Evaluate("ROW(1:" & iLastRow - 1 & ")") 'create an array of necessary existing rows number
    lastEmptyCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count + 1
    cells(1, lastEmptyCol + 1).value = "InitSort"     'place a header to the initial sort column
    cells(2, lastEmptyCol + 1).Resize(UBound(arrSort), 1).value = arrSort 'drop the array content in the column
    
    ReDim arrMark(1 To iLastRow - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        Select Case cells(i, "AD").value
            Case "TX", "OK", "AR", "LA"
            Case Else
                boolDel = True
                arrMark(i - 1, 1) = "Del"
            End Select
    Next i
    If boolDel Then
        With cells(2, lastEmptyCol).Resize(UBound(arrMark), 1)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'some optimization...
            .value = arrMark            'drop the arrMark content
            'sort the area where the above array content has been dropped:
             SortByColumn Range("A1", cells(iLastRow, lastEmptyCol + 1)), Range(cells(1, lastEmptyCol), cells(iLastRow, lastEmptyCol))
             .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete  'delete the rows containing "Del"
             'sort according to the original sheet initial sorting:
             SortByColumn Range("A1", cells(iLastRow, lastEmptyCol + 1)), Range(cells(1, lastEmptyCol + 1), cells(iLastRow, lastEmptyCol + 1)), True
             Range(cells(1, lastEmptyCol), cells(iLastRow, lastEmptyCol + 1)).Clear  'clear the helping column (the original sorting of the sheet)
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With
    End If
    Debug.Print "Markers: Delete rows in " & Round(Timer - tm, 2) & " sec (" & arrRepeat & ")"
End Sub

Sub SortByColumn(rng As Range, rngS As Range, Optional boolAscending As Boolean = False)
    rngS.cells(1).value = "LastColumn"
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=rngS, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=IIf(boolAscending, xlAscending, xlDescending), DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Then copy the `Union` range version:

```
Sub DeleteStateExceptionsUnion()
    Dim iLastRow As Long, rngDel As Range, i As Long
    Dim tm
    
    buildTestingRange arrRepeat
    
    tm = Timer
    iLastRow = cells(rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrMark(1 To iLastRow - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        Select Case cells(i, "AD").value
            Case "TX", "OK", "AR", "LA"
            Case Else
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = cells(i, "AD")
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cells(i, "AD"))
                End If
            End Select
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    Debug.Print "Union: Delete rows in " & Round(Timer - tm, 2) & " sec (" & arrRepeat & ")"
End Sub
```

And finally, the version using `Union` in batches, to avoid the code slowing down when such a range needs to be very large:

```
Sub DeleteStateExceptionsUnionBatch()
    Dim iLastRow As Long, rngDel As Range, i As Long
    Dim tm, batch As Long, count As Long
    
    buildTestingRange arrRepeat
    
    tm = Timer
    batch = 700
    iLastRow = cells(rows.count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrMark(1 To iLastRow - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = iLastRow To 2 Step -1              'iterate backwards
        Select Case cells(i, "AD").value
            Case "TX", "OK", "AR", "LA"
            Case Else
                count = count + 1
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = cells(i, "AD")
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cells(i, "AD"))
                End If
                If count >= batch Then
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                     rngDel.EntireRow.Delete: Set rngDel = Nothing: count = 0
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                End If
            End Select
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Debug.Print "Union batch: Delete rows in " & Round(Timer - tm, 2) & " sec (" & arrRepeat & ") batch: " & batch
End Sub
```

3. Now run each of the three versions for the same `arrRepeat` value. You fistly need to activate an empty sheet...

I obtained (in `Immediate Window`) the next running times:

```
Built testing range (5000 rows)
Markers: Delete rows in 0.33 sec (5000)
Built testing range (5000 rows)
Union: Delete rows in 24 sec (5000)
Built testing range (5000 rows)
Union batch: Delete rows in 18.79 sec (5000) batch: 600
Built testing range (5000 rows)
Union batch: Delete rows in 18.97 sec (5000) batch: 500
-------------------------------------------------------
Built testing range (10000 rows)
Markers: Delete rows in 0.43 sec (10000)
Built testing range (10000 rows)
Union: Delete rows in 51.23 sec (10000)
Built testing range (10000 rows)
Union batch: Delete rows in 14.57 sec (10000) batch: 500
--------------------------------------------------------
Built testing range (50000 rows)
Markers: Delete rows in 1.34 sec (50000)
Built testing range (50000 rows)
Union batch: Delete rows in 129.36 sec (50000) batch: 500
Built testing range (50000 rows)
Union batch: Delete rows in 125.47 sec (50000) batch: 600
Built testing range (50000 rows)
```

I tried Union range version but I had to close Excel after about 15 minutes...

Comment: I have not tried this method, I always did Union, I will time it against it

Comment: @Lio Djo I tried making some tests to compare the above code with other variants. It is indeed the fastest but it looks that **a limitation of `SpecialCells~ discontinuous range `Areas` exists for rows deletion. I discovered that after more than 32000 areas it is not able to delete all of them. I knew about the limitation of 8192 for versions up to 2007 inclusive, but I did not find any limitation in all documentation I read. This not meaning that I have read everything... Anyhow, I found a (theoretical) way to limit the areas and it will be extremely fast for even huge ranges.

Comment: @Lio Djo Not much time now to spend on the issue, but I will update it soon and let you know about it tagging you...

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Not-Criteria Rows

- When the criteria column is not sorted, it may take 'forever' to delete hundreds or even tens of thousands of rows.
- The following will insert and populate two columns, an integer sequence column, and the match column.
- After the data is sorted by the match column, the now contiguous range of error values will be used to quickly delete the undesired rows.
- The integer sequence column will be used to finally sort the data to regain the initial order.

```vb
Sub DeleteNotCriteriaRowsTEST()
    
    Const CriteriaList As String = "TX,OK,AR,LA"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "AD2"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    
    DeleteNotCriteriaRows FirstCell, CriteriaList

End Sub

Sub DeleteNotCriteriaRows( _
        ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal CriteriaList As String, _
        Optional ByVal CriteriaDelimiter As String = ",")
    Const ProcName As String = "DeleteNotCriteriaRows"
    Dim NothingToDelete As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, CriteriaDelimiter)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgColumn As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Set ws = .Worksheet
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count _
            - .Row + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set rgColumn = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim rgTotal As Range
    Set rgTotal = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rgColumn.EntireRow)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rgInsert As Range
    Set rgInsert = rgColumn.Cells(1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn
    rgInsert.Insert xlShiftToRight, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
    Dim rgIntegerSequence As Range: Set rgIntegerSequence = rgColumn.Offset(, 1)
    With rgIntegerSequence
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Formula = "=ROW()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    Dim rgMatch As Range: Set rgMatch = rgColumn.Offset(, 2)
    With rgMatch
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = Application.Match(rgColumn, Criteria, 0)
    End With
        
    rgTotal.Sort rgMatch, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    Dim rgDelete As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rgDelete = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, _
            rgMatch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
        
    If rgDelete Is Nothing Then
        NothingToDelete = True
    Else
        rgDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
        
    rgTotal.Sort rgIntegerSequence, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
        
    rgInsert.Offset(, -2).Delete xlShiftToLeft

SafeExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If NothingToDelete Then
        MsgBox "Nothing deleted.", vbExclamation, ProcName
    Else
        MsgBox "Rows deleted.", vbInformation, ProcName
    End If

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    NothingToDelete = True
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend keeping "sheet" specific and "use case specific" logic directly in cell formulas - then you can create more modular functions that can be reused.

In this scenario, if you add another column called "DeleteRow?",then populate it with a formula that returns "#DELETEROW#" when you want to delete the row else any other value* then you could have a reusable sub called "deleteRow" that takes listobject as an input and then sorts the data by column named "DeleteRow?", then filters on value "#DELETEROW#" and then deletes all filtered rows

Going forward, this approach let's you adjust the formula as needed to change which rows to delete without having to alter the vba.

* not tested but i bey if "DeleteRow?" formula returns `row()` when you want to keep the row, then the current sort will be preserved