# Optimize Performance of InStr check over range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to speed up the below `Sub()` that checks for the `-` character in a range? It is looping over 25000 rows across 3 columns and doesn't perform as fast as I'd like it to.

```
Sub Character_Check()

For Each tCell In Range("A1:C25000")
    If InStr(tCell.Text, "-") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "True"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just do `countif(a1:c25000,"-")`?

Comment: I think you would have to use `countif(a1:c25000,"*-*")` if you want to find cells with - anywhere in the text.

Comment: Alternative: Read the whole range into an 2-dimensional array and loop over that.

Comment: Thank you! @JohnRC this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to pass in multiple but separate characters? Looking to check for `-` and `{`. Also thank you @findwindow, I should have been more clear that I am looking for the character in the cells, not just the standalone `-`.

Comment: Depends what your purpose is. If you just want to know if there are any cells that contain either then use `countif(...) + countif(...)` with different chars in each. Cells that have both will be included twice.

Comment: @JohnRC Do `"` work with this method? Seems to throw an error when I try.

Comment: @JohnRC `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:C30000"), "*" & Chr(34) & "*")` seems to work for handling the `"` character.

Comment: If you need to use the quote " character in a literal string you can use two consecutive quotes to denote a single quote. So `Debug.Print "This is the quote "" character"` will output the string _This is the quote " character_ to the debug window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

For these scenarios (massive same computation) I think it's faster to store the values in an array and then just set the results to the range at once. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72382669/3221380) for a further explanation, by using it, we can see a substantial optimization.

**Code**

```
Sub Character_Check_2()
Dim DateTimeReportsRequest As Date: DateTimeReportsRequest = Now()
Dim arrMark As Variant
Dim CounterRow As Long
Dim CounterCol As Long
ReDim arrMark(1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1 To 1)
For CounterCol = 1 To 3 'A to C
For CounterRow = 2 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'Rows 2 to 25k
If InStr(Cells(CounterRow, CounterCol).Text, "-") > 0 Then arrMark(CounterRow, 1) = "TRUE"
Next CounterRow
Next CounterCol
    With Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(arrMark), 1)
    .Value = arrMark
    End With
MsgBox "Time to finish: " & DateDiff("s", DateTimeReportsRequest, Now()) & " seconds", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

**Demo**

Testing for the 25k in 3 columns (assuming it needs to write it to the sheet which it's very demanding), we go from 11secs to ~1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the below simple alternative and see if it improves the performance:

```
Sub Find_All()
   Dim rangeFirst As Range, rangeCurrent As Range
   Dim searchRange As Range
   Set searchRange = Range("A1:C25000")
   Do
      If rangeFirst Is Nothing Then
         Set rangeFirst = searchRange.Find(What:="-")
         Set rangeCurrent = rangeFirst
      Else
         Set rangeCurrent = searchRange.Find(What:="-", After:=rangeCurrent)
         If rangeCurrent.Address = rangeFirst.Address Then Exit Do
      End If
         MsgBox (rangeCurrent)
   Loop
End Sub
```