# Excel VBA Code Performance is slow on Large data

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this code which create a copy of workbook and take the first value from array and delete other entire rows with other value and save that workbook then go for 2nd value and so on

But this code is extremely slow on large datasets like 250K rows and 50 Columns. I hope there can be a quick way which can optimize the code.

```
    Sub Code2()
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
    Dim NewWB As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NewFilePath As String
    Dim NewWorkbookName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim KeepValues As Variant
    Dim wsNames As Variant
    Dim wsName As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim val As Variant
    ' Array of values to keep
    KeepValues = Array("Val1", "Val2", Val3)

    ' Array of worksheet names
    wsNames = Array("Sheet1","Sheet2")

    Set CurrentWB = ThisWorkbook
    FilePath = CurrentWB.FullName
    FolderPath = Left(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\"))

    For Each val In KeepValues
        NewWorkbookName = val & "_" & CurrentWB.Name
        NewFilePath = FolderPath & NewWorkbookName
        CurrentWB.SaveCopyAs NewFilePath
        Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(NewFilePath)

        For Each wsName In wsNames
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = NewWB.Sheets(wsName)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                With ws
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "CT").End(xlUp).Row
                    Set rng = .Range("CT2:CT" & lastRow)

                    ' Implementing the deletion technique
                    DeleteNotCriteriaRows rng, val

                    .AutoFilterMode = False
                End With
            End If
        Next wsName
        NewWB.RefreshAll
        'NewWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next val
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteNotCriteriaRows( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal Criteria As String)
    Const CriteriaDelimiter As String = ","
    Dim CriteriaList As String
    Dim rgColumn As Range
    Dim rCount As Long

    ' Construct Criteria List String
    CriteriaList = Criteria

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgTotal As Range

    Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Set rgColumn = rg

    Set rgTotal = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rgColumn.EntireRow)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rgInsert As Range
    Set rgInsert = rgColumn.Cells(1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn
    rgInsert.Insert xlShiftToRight, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Dim rgIntegerSequence As Range: Set rgIntegerSequence = rgColumn.Offset(, 1)
    With rgIntegerSequence
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Formula = "=ROW()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Dim rgMatch As Range: Set rgMatch = rgColumn.Offset(, 2)
    With rgMatch
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = Application.Match(rgColumn, Split(CriteriaList, CriteriaDelimiter), 0)
    End With

    rgTotal.Sort rgMatch, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo

    Dim rgDelete As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rgDelete = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, _
            rgMatch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rgDelete Is Nothing Then
        rgDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If

    rgTotal.Sort rgIntegerSequence, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo

    rgInsert.Offset(, -2).Delete xlShiftToLeft

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: prefer a different variable name than `Val`, as that shadows the [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function.

Comment: Not your issue here, but you should reset `ws` to `Nothing` before calling `Set ws = NewWB.Sheets(wsName)` - if that line fails then any previous assignment of `ws` will still be in place.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the delete rows, take a look on how to optimize this at the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382484/faster-or-best-alternative-for-vba-to-delete-rows-not-containing-specific-values)

Comment: "extremely slow" is roughly how long? Have you timed your code to find out where the slowness is?

Comment: Will try that @Tim Williams

Comment: When i run the code it stuck in first place and got error `Not Responding`

Comment: Look at Sgdva's suggestion - deleting rows can be very slow

Comment: I think this answer is the easiest to apply.  Basically sort all the rows to be deleted so they're as contiguous as possible, then delete. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401923/478884

Comment: Hey you're 100 percent right But i am in confusion that how to modify the code with this looking at since @Sgdva shared that.

Comment: `rng.Sort key1:=rng.Columns(1), Header:=xlNo` right before applying the autofilter

Comment: I have made an attempt to create this, but it is still taking time to process. I really do not want to inconvenience you, but considering your expertise, I believe you know how to address the minor issues that may take me years to notice. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.  https://codefile.io/f/rEFlSCv8m6  @Tim Williams

Comment: There is one more issue when its come to sorting the headers row becomes the last in each newly created workbook. I changed the parameter but issue is still same. `rgData.Sort Key1:=rgIntegerSequence, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
                OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom ' Exclude header row`

Comment: Do you have headers in Row1 ?

Comment: Yes I have the header row

Comment: Do your data tables start in A1 ?

Comment: If your code is working, but it's still slow, exactly how long (roughly) is it taking, and have you tested to see exactly where the slowness is?  If your files are huge then just saving and opening is going to take some time.   Is it important to return the sort order to the original after deleting the rows?  If Yes then is there not already a column in your data which could be used for that final re-sort?

Comment: Not yet tested because saving and opening workbook takes all time other things are perfect. The code is currently creating 3 workbooks which took me almost 60 seconds plus.

Comment: "saving and opening workbook takes all time" if that's the case then you have likely hit the limit on how much this can be improved.  Possibly it might be faster if you copy and rename the source file directly on disk, then open each copy to process it, instead of using SaveCopyAs to create the copies.

Comment: If you could provide a solution based on your expertise and assist in fixing the sorting issue. Your help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Sub Code2()
    
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, NewWB As Workbook
    Dim NewFilePath As String, NewWorkbookName As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim KeepValues As Variant, wsNames As Variant, wsName As Variant
    Dim val As Variant
    
    KeepValues = Array("Val1", "Val2", "Val3") ' values to keep
    wsNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'worksheet names to process

    Set CurrentWB = ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each val In KeepValues
        NewFilePath = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & val & "_" & CurrentWB.Name
        CurrentWB.SaveCopyAs NewFilePath
        Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(NewFilePath)

        For Each wsName In wsNames
            Set ws = GetNamedWorksheet(NewWB, wsName)
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                DeleteNonMatches ws, "CT", val
            End If
        Next wsName
        NewWB.RefreshAll
        'NewWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next val
    
End Sub

'get worksheet named `sheetName` from workbook `wb`: returns `Nothing` if not found
Function GetNamedWorksheet(wb As Workbook, sheetName) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetNamedWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
End Function

'Delete all rows from data on worksheet `ws` where value in named
'  column `header` does not match `KeepValue`
'Assumes data starts in A1 with no empty rows or columns, and first row is headers
Sub DeleteNonMatches(ws As Worksheet, header As String, ByVal KeepValue As String)
    
    Dim rng As Range, m As Variant, nc As Long
    Dim rgInsert As Range
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'assuming no empty rows or columns
    m = Application.Match(header, rng.Rows(1), 0)
    
    If IsError(m) Then
        MsgBox "Header not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'add an additional column so we can re-sort at the end
    Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
    nc = rng.Columns.Count
    With rng.Columns(nc) 'add values and header
        .Value = Application.Evaluate("=ROW(" & .Address(False, False) & ")")
        .Cells(1).Value = "XsortX"
    End With
    
    rng.Sort key1:=rng.Columns(m), header:=xlYes 'sort rows to be hidden together
    With rng.Columns(m) 'filter and delete visible rows
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & KeepValue
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False 'clear filter
    
    're-sort to original order and remove the temporary column
    rng.Sort key1:=rng.Columns(nc), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
    rng.Columns(nc).EntireColumn.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I believe there's an issue occurring when the workbook is created and it deletes all rows except for the first and second ones. I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening. If you don't mind, I could share my workbook with you so you can help me figure out why this is occurring.

Comment: OK - go ahead and share, but please remove any code no relevant to this task: I will need to review all code before allowing macros in your workbook.

Comment: will upload it on different site then. Sure please

Comment: Please let me know when you have time so I can share the link, because workbook contains confidential data. Thanks

Comment: Was this resolved then?

Comment: Not by me, in the end.  Turned out the use case was slightly different from what was in the posted code.